# I have a 3 way mixed anova. The 3 way interaction is not significant

Tags: mixed-model, anova, interaction

Let's say it is info (2 factors), time (2 factors), and a group ( athletes or no). The three-way interaction is not significant but the info X group is significant. What t-test should I do paired or independent?

Answer (score 0):

You do paired tests when the data are actually paired. For example, if the same individuals were evaluated at both values of `time`, then a paired test of some sort might be appropriate. If this really is a "mixed" model (as stated in the title) with random effects for individuals, however, then the pairing has already been taken into account by the random effects and you should work directly with the fixed-effect regression-coefficient estimates.

With the interactions in this ANOVA design you have to be careful about what you are comparing and how you are doing it. Comparisons among different combinations of predictor values need to take both the underlying regression coefficients of the model and their covariance matrix into account. If you are making [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem) based on the same model (for example, comparing all 8 combinations of `info` and `time` and `group`), you also need to take the number of comparisons into account. That's all usually done via separate software functions, in what's often called "post-hoc" analysis.